# How do I use Each() for retuned list in Ajax/JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problem to use `foreach` inside AJAX method. I pass the list from `Test` controller to the said AJAX method. I'm using `Append()` to create a customized content but having trouble with listing all courses.

```
 $.post("/Home/Test", { "id": id },
     function (data) {
         if (data) {    

             $("#testDiv").append($('<div class=\"studentInfo\"> ' +
             '<br/> ' +
              <b>Student: </b>' + data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName +
              '<br/>' +
              '<b>School: </b>' + data.SchoolName +
              '<br/>' +
              '<b>All courses: </b>' 

               //How to "foreach" all course inside "data.Courses"? 

               +'</div>'));

         }
    });
```

Comment: `$.each(data.Courses(function(index, item) { console.log(item); })`

Answer (score 2):

Use this sample code:

Sample Code:

HTML:

```
<table id="idOfmyTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
                <th>Column3</th>
                <th>Column4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function getAllRecords(rootPath) {
    $.getJSON(rootPath , function(response) {
        $("#idOfmyTable").find('tbody').empty(); // Added to remove "No data available in table" message in first row after loading data
        $.each(response, function(idx, obj) {

            var body = "<tr>";
            body    += "<td>" + obj.column1 + "</td>";
            body    += "<td>" + obj.column2 + "</td>";
            body    += "<td>" + obj.column3 + "</td>";
            body    += "<td>" + obj.column4 + "</td>";
            body    += "</tr>";
            $( "#idOfmyTable tbody" ).append(body);
        });

        $('#idOfmyTable').DataTable();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your same mechanism, just loop through your courses, generate html for each one, append it to a variable, and then include that in the end.

```
$.post("/Home/Test", {
  "id": id
},
function(data) {
  if (data) {

    var courses = '';

    data.Courses.forEach(function(course) {
      courses += '<b>' + course + '</b>';
    });

    $("#testDiv").append($('<div class=\"studentInfo\"> ' +
          '<br/> ' +
          < b > Student: < /b>' + data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName +
          '<br/ > ' +
          ' < b > School: < /b>' + data.SchoolName +
          '<br/ > ' +
          ' < b > All courses: < /b>' + courses

           +'</div > '));

     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Basic Operation:**

```
 $.each(data.Courses, function (index, item)
  {
    var yourCurrentCource= item;
  })
```

**In your case It should be like this.**

```
$.post("/Home/Test", { "id": id },
    function (data) {
        if (data) {
            //Generate Cource HTML
            var allCources;
            $.each(data.Courses, function (index, item) {
                allCources += '<b>' + item + '</b>'; // generate html string here
            })

            $("#testDiv").append($('<div class=\"studentInfo\"> ' +
            '<br/> ' +
             '<b>Student: </b>' + data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName +
            '<br/>' +
            '<b>School: </b>' + data.SchoolName +
            '<br/>' +
            '<b>All courses: </b>' + allCources
             + '</div>'));

        }
    });
```